# Error is showing when importing the Slides in Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am working in my Ionic 4 app and I have imported the Slides in my app but it is showing the error.

This is my **intro.page.ts**:

```
import { Slides } from '@ionic/angular';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-intro',
  templateUrl: './intro.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./intro.page.scss'],
})
export class IntroPage implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('slides') slides: Slides;
  constructor(private storage: Storage, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  next() {
    this.slides.slideNext();
  }
}
```

Error:

> Module
>   '"../../../../../Users/challengesnew/node_modules/@ionic/angular/dist/core"'
>   has no exported member 'Slides'.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the GitHub [issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/16737) and the mentioned [changelog](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#angular-prefixed-ion--components),
all ionic components are prefixed with `Ion` if you want to import.

Change your import to:

```
import { IonSlides } from '@ionic/angular';
```

and

```
 @ViewChild('slides') slides: IonSlides;
```

Answer (score 2):

Now, With Angular 8, while the import stays the same:

```
import { IonSlides } from '@ionic/angular';
```

in the *@ViewChild* decorator, the *static* property is required inside the *options* parameter, as following:

```
@ViewChild('slides', {static: true}) slides: IonSlides;
```